# Is there a better way to say "since the hour last changed"?

Tags: idioms, time

I am looking for a better, possibly idiomatic, phrase to describe the place in time "since the hour last changed".

A simplistic example: if the time was 6.31pm, it would be thirty-one minutes *since the hour last changed*. Another usage could be for whenever a counter is reset every hour, on the hour. For example, if a counter estimating the children born in the world was reset each hour, is there a better way to say "*X* children were born *since the hour changed*"?

Comment: "since the top of the hour"

Comment: @Chappo it's worth pointing out that "the top of the hour" is an Americanism.  That was my understanding at least, and Merriam Webster seems to agree. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at%20the%20top%20of%20the%20hour

Comment: A native British English speaker, I recognised 'top of the hour' but as @MaxWilliams notes (and as the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=top+of+the+hour&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctop%20of%20the%20hour%3B%2Cc0) shows, it is hugely more usual in AmE than BrE.

Comment: If you were going to document the number of children as X, you would know what the hour had been which was just passed, so you would just say 'since Y hour, X children ...'.

Comment: @MaxWilliams it was the first phrase that occurred to me, and I'm Australian, so I think it's quite widely understood.

Comment: @NigelJ true but I am supposing a simple, generic counter in my example, maybe one that shows on a web page but does not update its displayed message each hour (just the count).

Comment: "X children have been born" [Updated hourly.]

Comment: “Updated hourly” still leaves the possibility for some ambiguity, in my opinion.

Comment: @blairnangle in the specific situation you describe I think it would be best to say "X children born since 6 pm" or whatever, and avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I prefer *since the top of the hour* to anything else, myself. (It's much more natural sounding than the one answer currently given.) Even if it is an Americanism (and I think it's clear that it's recognized in other countries), your question doesn't specify that it being so would invalidate it.

Comment: @JasonBassford I concur. Chappo's suggestion is not invalid and does make sense. It's just that "struck the hour" is something I have actually heard before (albeit not for a few years) and so instantly makes sense to me, personally.

Comment: How about "in the current hour"? This would be unambiguous in all time zones based on full hours from GMT  like Eastern Seaboard Time or Beijing Time. However there are time zones like Newfoundland time which are based on fractions of hours from GMT (Newfoundland Time is GMT -2:30 or GMT -3:30 depending on whether its Summer or Winter). This could cause confusion if your website is supposed to be worldwide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may sound old-fashioned, but this *sounds* idiomatic: *since the clock last **struck the hour***

> "X children were born *since the clock last **struck the hour***"

Macmillan:

> **[strike the hour](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/strike-the-hour)**
>   *PHRASE*
>
> if a clock strikes the hour, it shows that it is exactly one o’clock,
>   two o’clock etc by making a sound once, twice etc

Wikipedia:

> [Striking clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Striking_clock) (some background)
>
> A striking clock (also known as chiming clock) is a clock that sounds
>   the hours audibly on a bell or gong. In 12-hour striking, used most
>   commonly in striking clocks today, the clock strikes once at 1:00
>   A.M., twice at 2:00 A.M., continuing in this way up to twelve times at
>   12:00 P.M., then starts again, striking once at 1:00 P.M., twice at
>   2:00 P.M., up to twelve times at 12:00 A.M.

Surprisingly, the usage of this term seems to be picking up as per this Google [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clock%20struck%20the%20hour&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclock%20struck%20the%20hour%3B%2Cc0):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To formalize some comments made to the question itself, another idiomatic phrase is [**at the top of the hour**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at%20the%20top%20of%20the%20hour):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> *US*
> : at the beginning of the hour (at 12:00, 1:00, 2:00, etc.)
> // The program is scheduled to start *at the top of the hour*.

As noted by Merriam-Webster, this has primarily US usage. However, it is used elsewhere as well.

In the particular sentence in question, it could be expressed as:

> X children were born since the top of the hour.

In contrast, there is also *at the bottom of the hour*, but this is less common and it doesn't have a similar entry in Merriam-Webster.

---

If we go by the printed word alone, [Google's Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=struck%20the%20hour%2Ctop%20of%20the%20hour&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstruck%20the%20hour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctop%20of%20the%20hour%3B%2Cc0) shows almost equal usage between *at the top of the hour* and *struck the hour*:

[image: top_of_the_hour]

What's interesting is that *struck the hour* used to be a lot more common. For whatever reason, its *general* trend has been to decline. Meanwhile, the use of *top of the hour* has been increasing since about 1985.

If you change the corpus used, you'll see that *top of the hour* is actually slightly more common in the US—but that in the UK it's noticeably less common (although still in use).